# Spark DF schema verification with Decimal column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to verify the schema of a Spark dataframe against schema information it get from some other source (a dashboard tool). The information I get about the table is field name and field type (nullability is not important at this point).
However, for `DecimalType` columns I do not get the information about precision and scale (the two parameters of DecimalType). So I have to ignore these values in the comparison.

I currently re-write the schema so that the Decimal columns become Float column. But is there a more elegant way to do that?

Basically I want to write a function `is_schema_valid()` that works as such:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField('column_1', T.StringType(), True),
    T.StructField('column_2', T.DecimalType(20,5), True), # values in DecimalType are random
])

schema_info = [('column_1', 'String'), ('column_2', 'Decimal')]

is_schema_valid(schema_info, df_schema)
# Output: True
```

Comment: do you need that specific format for `schema_info` or can we use dict ?

Comment: No, the format is free to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would probably to compare similar objects. You can transform a schema in JSON object (or python dict).

```py
import json 

_df_schema_dict = json.loads(df_schema.json())
df_schema_dict = {
    field["name"]: field["type"]
    for field in _df_schema_dict["fields"]
}

df_schema_dict
> {'column_1': 'string', 'column_2': 'decimal(20,5)'}
```

You can work with this object to compare with `schema_info`. Here is a very basic test you can do (I change a bit the content of `schema_info`):

```py
import json


def is_schema_valid(schema_info, df_schema):

    df_schema_dict = {
        field["name"]: field["type"] for field in json.loads(df_schema.json())["fields"]
    }

    schema_info_dict = {elt[0]: elt[1] for elt in schema_info}

    return schema_info_dict == df_schema_dict


df_schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("column_1", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("column_2", T.DecimalType(20, 5), True),
    ]
)
schema_info = [("column_1", "string"), ("column_2", "decimal(20,5)")]

is_schema_valid(schema_info, df_schema)
# True
```

---

If you want to ignore `decimal` precision, you can always twist a little bit the dataframe schema. Replace `field["type"]` with `field["type"] if "decimal" not in field["type"] else "decimal"` for example.

```py
import json


def is_schema_valid(schema_info, df_schema):

    df_schema_dict = {
        field["name"]: field["type"] if "decimal" not in field["type"] else "decimal"
        for field in json.loads(df_schema.json())["fields"]
    }

    schema_info_dict = {elt[0]: elt[1] for elt in schema_info}

    return schema_info_dict == df_schema_dict


df_schema = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField("column_1", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("column_2", T.DecimalType(20, 5), True),
    ]
)
schema_info = [("column_1", "string"), ("column_2", "decimal")]

is_schema_valid(schema_info, df_schema)
# True
```

Comment: @tilpiffl  I made a final edit to my answer.